# multiple definition in C project

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a problem with this project (it is a minigame similar to space invaders).
Every time I try to compile it it gives me these errors:

```
❯ make
gcc main.o collisioni.o stampa.o gestione.o -o progetto -lncurses
/usr/bin/ld: collisioni.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `maxx'; main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: collisioni.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `maxy'; main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: collisioni.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `flag_navicelle'; main.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: stampa.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `maxx'; main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: stampa.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `maxy'; main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: stampa.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `flag_navicelle'; main.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: gestione.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `maxx'; main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: gestione.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `maxy'; main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: progetto] Errore 1
```

The source code of the project is this:  https://github.com/Stenafo/game
I compile the code using the makefile.
I don't understand where the problem is, a friend of mine manages to compile it without errors.
This project uses processes, however I have the same problem with threads.

Comment: Please don't link to external resources, post a [mre] in your question, yes, you can [edit] it. -- Most probably you define these variables in the header files. Don't do it, declare them, and define them in an appropriate source file.

Comment: Ask the repository owner about this problem, add an [issue](https://github.com/Stenafo/game/issues)

Comment: Try `make clean` first, then `make`.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX the owner is me

Comment: @dbush I already did that but didn't work

Comment: The header `globale.h` defines variables `int maxx, maxy;`. That means each C file including that header will have an own copy of this definition causing the error. That should be `extern` declarations with a single definition in one of the C files. That a bug in the code.

Comment: @Gerhardh I tried to use extern but it gives me even more errors. I don't know how to fix :(   I have tried removing the declaration from globale.h and putting it in a .c file but that also doesn't solve

Comment: Precisely one source file should define those variables.  Maybe the one that defines `main()`.  That file must include the header too to ensure that the declarations in the header are consistent with the definitions.  The header must only declare the variables — prefix the declaration with `extern`.  Include the header in every source file that references any of the variables.

Comment: Make them `extern` in the header and put the same line without `extern` into **one** of your C files. But generally, the repository maintainer should fix that.

Comment: This should give you an example of using `extern` on global variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71627232/use-of-global-variables-between-two-files-in-c/71627353#71627353

Comment: Note that before GCC 10.1.0, GCC used a default option `-fcommon`; in GCC 10.1.0 and later, that was changed to `-fno-common`.  (As of 2022-04-10, GCC 11.2.0 is current; GCC 12.1.0 is nearing release.) The change means that code which broke the ODR (one definition rule) — for example by defining variables in headers — no longer links (it still compiles OK). One possible, but undesirable, option is to add `-fcommon` to the compiler options. Of course, if you are not using GCC 10.x or later (or a corresponding version of Clang), then this is not relevant. I see you are using some version of GCC.

Comment: regarding: `read(pipein, &valore_letto, sizeof(valore_letto));`  always check the returned value so you know how many characters were actually read